# Width of headerbox columns in baposters

Tags: baposter

I'm using this [template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/baposter-landscape-poster) for a conference. I changed it to be a portrait poster.
Now I want this structure:

[image: Structure]

The problem is that I don't know how to construct that two boxes in the third row. Anyone has some idea?

Comment: It would be good if you could post a sample of your code from the template. It would make this post self-contained (in the event that the link expires or is changed) and give the community (and future visitors) easy access to the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same template can be forced to be portrait and with 6 columns (mcm for 1,2,3). Then it's easy to arrange your desired distribution:

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% baposter Landscape Poster
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (11/06/13)
%
% baposter Class Created by:
% Brian Amberg (baposter@brian-amberg.de)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt, % Width of the border lines around content boxes
columns=6
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
{\includegraphics[height=4em]{example-image}} % First university/lab logo on the left
{\bf\textsc{Unnecessarily Complicated Research Title}\vspace{0.5em}} % Poster title
{\textsc{\{ John Smith, James Smith and Jane Smith \}\\ University and Department Name}} % Author names and institution
{\includegraphics[height=4em]{example-image}} % Second university/lab logo on the right

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Objectives}{name=objectives,column=0,row=0,span=6}{
\lipsum[1]
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,below=objectives,span=6}{
\lipsum[2-3]
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Results 1}{name=results,below=introduction,column=0,span=3}{
\lipsum[3-4]
}

\headerbox{Results 2}{name=results,below=introduction,column=3,span=3}{
\lipsum[3-4]
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0,span=2,above=bottom}{
\lipsum[2]
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FUTURE RESEARCH
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Future Research}{name=futureresearch,column=2,span=2,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block

\lipsum[2]
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Contact Information}{name=contact,column=4,span=2,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block

\lipsum[2]
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!